# Can't instanciate Slim object

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to make an RESTful API for an AngularJS app using Slim. I just started to cod and I already have a problem. I' just trying to instantiate Slim and i t tells me:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\App' not found in /home/kevdug/webapps/angularjs/api/index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/kevdug/webapps/angularjs/api/index.php on line 10

I have an 'api' directorie and in it, I got my 'index.php' file and a 'vendor' folder (the folder generated by composer when I installed Slim)

here is my index.php file:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
        echo "The file $filename exists";
    } else {
        echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    }

    $app = new \Slim\App();
    //$app = new Slim();

    //$app->run();

    ?>
```

And my code does tell me that the aitoload.php file exist.

The weird thing is that I exactly followed the exemple on the Slim website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.............. Turns out I'm just an idiot and I didn't have to put parentheses after App:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->run();

?>
```